Вывод фактов prolog
Я хочу написать clauses на вывод фактов, моя попытка в самум низу кода, в run. Но у меня не получается это реализовать, как это сделать?
predicates
figure(id,color,row,col)
nondeterm figure(integer, symbol, integer, integer).
walk(id,x,y)
nondeterm walk(integer,integer,integer).


clauses
figure(1,white,1,1).
figure(2,white,1,3).
figure(3,white,1,5).
figure(4,white,1,7).
figure(5,white,2,1).
figure(6,white,2,4).
figure(7,white,2,6).
figure(8,white,2,8).
figure(9,white,3,1).
figure(10,white,3,3).
figure(11,white,3,5).
figure(12,white,3,7).

figure(13,black,8,2).
figure(14,black,8,4).
figure(15,black,8,6).
figure(16,black,8,8).
figure(17,black,7,1).
figure(18,black,7,3).
figure(19,black,7,5).
figure(20,black,7,7).
figure(21,black,6,2).
figure(22,black,6,4).
figure(23,black,6,6).
figure(24,black,6,8).

run:- 
    figure(A, B, C, D),
        write(figure(A, B, C, D)), nl,fail.

goal
    run.


что именно должно происходить при выполнении твоего кода? Что происходит сейчас?

сейчас ошибка, я хочу все факты(clauses) вывести в консоль

какая ошибка? Зачем write(figure(A, B, C, D)) если нужно вывести только A, B, C, D

это я экспериментировал как вывести, не получается чет

не пробовал write(A, B, C, D)?

ну напишу a b c d, а откуда данные в них возьмутся?

так ты попробуй :)

написал так - run:-
figure(A, B, C, D),
write(A, B, C, D).
такая ошибка
E;Test_Goal, pos: 811, 404 Undeclared predicate, misspelling or not supported on chosen platform run

а откуда ты взял write и где вообще запускаешь? что именно за пролог?

а все заработала, я забыл оказывается определить ранее предикат run
